# Python/GTK3 app crashing on importing "indicate" (python-indicate)

Tags: python, application-development, messaging-menu, gtk3, appindicator

I'm trying to integrate my Python/GTK3 app with Ubuntu's messaging menu and every time I try to import "indicate" (python-indicate) my app crashes, with the following traceback:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gobject/constants.py:24: Warning: g_boxed_type_register_static: assertion `g_type_from_name (name) == 0' failed
  import gobject._gobject
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: specified class size for type `PyGtkGenericCellRenderer' is smaller than the parent type's `GtkCellRenderer' class size
  from gtk import _gtk
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: g_type_get_qdata: assertion `node != NULL' failed
  from gtk import _gtk
```

This looks like some sort of clash between GTK2 and GTK3... anyway, how would I go about fixing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
from gi.repository import Indicate
```

instead of

```
import indicate
```

Comment: Also check out the PyGI example on http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/application-indicators/

Comment: the same thing for `vte` module: `from gi.repository import Vte`

Comment: Same for importing `Gdk`, `GLib`, `Pango`, `GdkPixbuf` and `GObject` from gi.repository instead of their older alternatives. It seems it's impossible to import GTK2 and GTK3 at the same time.